# kotlin companion object field with debugger

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, kotlin, static-variables

I declare a field in companion object, so it will be known in the functions in the companion object.

something like this:

```
class ProgramStructure {
  companion object {
      var index = 0
      fun inc(){
          index++
      }
  }
}
```

Everything work perfect, but when I debugging it I can't see the value of "index".
How can I see the value?

Thanks

Comment: It was failing in debugger with some exceptions, then I searched for it, then tried again and it started working so I really don't know now, but there is nothing new in this answer for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are using IntelliJ IDEA.

Since `index` is neither a local variable nor a field of the current instance, there's no straightforward way to see its value in the debugger.

If you need to evaluate `index` once, you can use the *Evaluate Expression* action (the default keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>), which is available in the debug window:

[image]

Then type `index`:

[image]

Another way to evaluate an expression is to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click it in the editor, or select it and press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

---

If you want to watch the `index` values over time, consider adding a watch (*New Watch*, <kbd>Insert</kbd> in the debug window, or from the *Evaluate Expression* dialog), and here's how it looks with the watch:

[image]